# Why is my Google Chat bot not available for other G-Suite users apart from my domain?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-hangouts, google-chat

I have created a Google Chatbot using the Google Hangouts Chat API. The bot has been verified on the store listing of GSuite Marketplace SDK. App visibility is also set to the public mode.

- ## Store Listing Status:

[image]

- ## App Visibility Status:

[image]

I have also got my OAuth Consent Screen verified and set to external.

Can anyone let me know, what might be the reason that my Chatbot is not available to other G-Suite domain accounts?

- ## OAuth Verification Status:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the bot is not available? Please be aware that it will not appear among apps listed in the Marketplace, but it will just be discoverable by users via autocomplete: `As of this writing, when you publish your bot to G Suite Marketplace it does not appear among the apps listed there. However, it is still discoverable by users because it will appear in the autocomplete. Expect to see bot listings added to the G Suite Marketplace user experience in the future.` ([ref](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/gsm-list)). Could you check if that's what's going on?

Comment: If you try searching in bot catalogue, it say's not found.
Whereas if I share the direct link, says unavailable to install. Link: https://chat.google.com/u/1/botcatalog/details/111765543174144535286

Comment: You've gone through the review process, right? Do you have access to G Suite support? If that's the case, I'd suggest you to contact [them](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213), or to the review team.